# PHP & MySQL - How to count the number of records

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I have this web site search script and I'm trying to count how many records will be displayed when the user enters there search term or terms. I was wondering how would I be able to do this when i don't know what keywords will be entered?

Below is my search query.

Here is the part of my PHP & MySQL search code.

```
$search_explode = explode(" ", $search);

foreach($search_explode as $search_each) {
    $x++;
    if($x == 1){
        $construct .= "article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    } else {
        $construct .= "OR article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }

}

$construct = "SELECT users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles
              INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
              WHERE $construct";
```

Here is the first error.

```
MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles INNER JOIN users O' at line
```

Here is the second error.

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Comment: Escape your input!! [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), unless you feel like going all the way to use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and prepared statements. No other way to avoid big errors and getting hacked.

Comment: I know all about that I left it out of my code for know thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the part of your SQL query after `FROM` in a variable then you can use `COUNT(*)` to get the amount of rows:

```
$search_explode = explode(" ", $search);

foreach($search_explode as $search_each) {
    $x++;
    if($x == 1){
        $construct .= "article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    } else {
        $construct .= "OR article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }

}

$from = "FROM users_articles
         INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
         WHERE $construct";

$count_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) " . $from;

$result = mysql_query($count_query);
$count_result = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$count = $count_result[0];
```

Comment: How would I do that? sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row($result)[0]` is not legal PHP syntax. You'd have to store the row array in a variable first before accessing its index.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks! Coming from a `C/C++` background, i sometimes forget this pitfall of `PHP`.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Comment: +1. If the query is simple, running two might be fine. But if the query is complicated, and you're not doing pagination, this is the best way to go.

Comment: @Matchu I'm doing pagination I just can't count the number of rows.

Comment: @Ione, then my solution is appropriate.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin for some reason I get an error trying to use your code any suggestions?

Comment: @Ione, try my revised answer.